# Use a QAbstractListModel in another one

Tags: c++, qt, qml, datamodel, qabstractlistmodel

I have an issue while trying to develop a data model for my application with Qt/QML.
I already used a `QAbstractListModel` to be able to pass customs data model from C++ to QML and it worked like a charm with simple model (such as a model based on strings and bools).

But now I need to build a more difficult model and I was wondering if it was possible to use a `QAbstractListModel` inside another `QAbstractListModel`.

Let me explain myself.
I have a data model called `model_A` build like that :

model_A.h:

```
#ifndef MODEL_A_H
#define MODEL_A_H

#include <QAbstractListModel>
#include <QList>

class model_A
{
public:
   model_A(const QString& _string1,const QString& _string2,const bool& _bool);
   QString m_string1;
   QString m_string2;
   bool m_bool;
};
class abstractmodel_A : QAbstractListModel
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   (here I implemented all the roles functions and overloaded fonctions needed for the model to work)
private:
   QList<model_A> m_model_A;
};        
#endif // ANSWERS_H
```

And then I need to use that model inside another one called `model_B`:

model_B.h:

```
#ifndef MODEL_B_H
#define MODEL_B_H

#include <QAbstractListModel>
#include <QList>
#include "model_A.h"

class model_B
{
public:
   model_B(const QString& _string1,const QString& _string2,const abstractmodel_A& _modelA);
   QString m_string1;
   QString m_string2;
   abstractmodel_A m_modelA;
};
class abstractmodel_B : QAbstractListModel
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   (here I implemented all the roles functions and overloaded fonctions needed for the model to work)
   QList<model_B> m_model_B;
};        
#endif // ANSWERS_H
```

Is this possible, with all the restriction problem of the DISABLE_COPY of the QAbstractListModel or should I find another way to build my data model ?

Thank you.

Comment: if you use pointers than it will work

Comment: thank you for that advice. I think i manage to get it to work from the c++ side. but do you know how I could acces the roles of the model_A through the model_B in qml ?

Comment: You're question is not clear for me - how do you want to use model A in model B? What goals you want to achieve?

Comment: I was looking for a method in order to be abble to implement a QAbstractModel in an other one. like if i had defined a model called wheel compound of a wheel rim and a tire and i wanted to use that model in a model car compound of wheels, and other stuff. Don't know if my example will help you in the understanding of my goal. But in any case, mcchu gave me an answer that works with me. Thank you for the time you spent for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `model_B`, you can store a pointer to `abstractmodel_A` so DISABLE_COPY won't be a problem:

```
class model_B
{
public:
   abstractmodel_A * m_modelA;
};

model_B modelBObject;
modelBObject.m_modelA = new abstractmodel_A(/*parent*/);
```

Next, create `model_A_role` in `abstractmodel_B` so QML can access model A in delegates. Inside `abstractmodel_B::data` function, you have to convert `abstractmodel_A *` to `QVariant`. Since `abstractmodel_A` inheirts from `QAbstractListModel`, which is a `QObject`, the type conversion can simply be done like this:

```
QVariant abstractmodel_B::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    //...
    if (role == Model_A_Role)
    {
        return QVariant::fromValue<QObject *>(m_model_B[index.row()].m_modelA);
    }
}
```

Finally back to QML, use ListView to handle C++ models:

```
ListView {
    model: model_B
    delegate: Item {
        ListView {
            model: model_A_role
            delegate: DelegateForModelA { /*...*/ }
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

And `DelegateForModelA` can directly access roles in `model_A`.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Thank you it works well as you described it !

Comment: Appreciate this :)