# QAbstracktListModel which consists of QAbstractListModels. How to implement?

Tags: c++, qtquick2, qt-quick, qabstractitemmodel, qabstractlistmodel

I need to have List whitch contains Lists. It's not a tree.
So the problem is that I need to dynamically get new data models from QML.
Can I implement `QAbstractItemModel` and use in in `TreeView`??
How to implement this? I have zero ideas (

Comment: Can you fill one model with different data? Or user one model but with different underlying storage like dynamic arrays or vectors or some other containers?

Comment: @user3528438 yeah, I can. But how can I use this data in the interior ListView?

Comment: You can implement the `data` method to use what ever data storage you want.

Comment: @user3528438 I do not see way to implement this.
`ListView {
  ListView {
  }
}`
to make it work it must operate with data models. so how can I implement data function to return a data model??

Comment: I don't think that data() function can return QAbstractListModels directly, because QAbstractListModel can't be put in QVariant. So, wrap the pointer in some simple class. Btw, this question may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29558138/use-a-qabstractlistmodel-in-another-one

Comment: Sounds slightly similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32181462/using-tableview-as-listview-delegate.